# How to make element appear on top of html, without affecting layout

Tags: html, seo

Below is a statement that I have learned from SEO experts:

In subpages of a webpage, there may be several links to homepage. But the first link to homepage should have useful text words within  tags, because this link will be the only one a crawler will take care.

Assuming the above is correct, and having the below code:

```html
<div class="topImage">
  <a href="/" title="topImage"><img src="url"></a>
</div>

<div class="imageBelow">
  <a href="/" title="imageBelow">Useful SEO Text</a>
</div>
```

...how can I make the second link (text) appear above the first link (this is an image) in the source code, **without** affecting the layout of the webpage? Is this possible?

Comment: you want to replace it or make a slide in entry?

Comment: Here, take a look at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qcc7fqjp/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean with the whole SEO thing.
And you can do it your way with a little CSS

**Option 1:**

```
.imageBelow {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:10;
 }
.topImage {
     z-index:0;
 }
```

But the better way to do this in my opinion is, to give the `<a>` tag in the div with the class '.topImage' a background image. then you can put all of the seo text in there like the following example, and give it a 'text-indent' with a very high negative value. In that manner the crawlers can see the text and use it for optimisation but you've got less html and no multiple links

**Option 2**

```
<!-- HTML PART //-->
<div class="topImage">
    <a href="/" title="top-image">IMPORTANT SEO TEXT</a>
</div>

/* CSS PART */
.topImage > a {
    background:url(*path to your image*) left top no-repeat;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-indent:-999em !important;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Moving elements around on a page with CSS have no effect at all on how a searchengine will index a webpage. But it can somehow be usefull to increase feedback from humans. +1 for showing OP how it can be done anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should not care about those socalled experts. **Any** search engine will ultimately follow and index *every* link on your page, regardless if the link points to an external or as in your example an internal resource. Unless you actively tell search engines not to index certain pages by for example a [robots.txt disallow](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) instruction.

The key point here is not "SEO", but simply building your webpage properly. That is, using the correct HTML tags for your content and take advantage of HTML attributes as they were meant to be used.

With this in mind there is a few simple "tricks" you can use to heavily increase a search engines willingness to follow and index the links in your example.

```
<div class="topImage">
  <a href="/" title="topImage"><img src="url"></a>
</div>
```

There is nothing here to attract the search engine, and the link is completely useless in a "SEO"-context. It is just an image with a link. You must give the engine some bait through the `<a>` tags `title` attribute and the `<img>` tags `title` and `alt` attributes as well. This is very important when having `<img>`-links only.

```
<section class="topImage">
  <a href="/" title="a description of your page (this link is going to the frontpage, right? Why describe the topImage?">
     <img src="url" title="here more details about your page" alt="even more ..">
  </a>
</section>
```

Use a `<section>` tag instead of a `<div>` tag, telling the engine that this is an important part of your webpage. In HTML5, the `<div>` tag should be used for block styling only, not for separating content into logical units. Use the `title`-attribute everywhere you can, and *always* remember to be smart using keywords describing your page, also in titles! Like `title="Buy cellphones and smartphones, click here"`.  You have about 50 characters in each title tag to improve the overall description of your site. Use them!

```
<div class="imageBelow">
  <a href="/" title="imageBelow">Useful SEO Text</a>
</div>
```

Again, take advantage of the very important `title` tag, and if the link is an important link, wrap it into a header tag, like a `<h3>`, telling the search engine that this text and this link have significant importance for your webpage.

```
<section class="imageBelow" title="sections supports the title attribute">
  <h3 title="header tags also supports the title attribute as well">
    <a href="/" title="50 characters of description">more useful SEO Text</a>
  </h3> 
</section>
```

The above advices is very effective for how a search engine see your page. Mingling around with elements in CSS has no effect at all. And replacing `<section>`'s with `<div>`'s and so on does not affect the layout.

Comment: Nice answer.. learned something today. I did not know that the `<section>` tag was that important to search engines. Thanks vote you one up!

Comment: @Paul, I have worked with this issue in practice. And consulted SEO "experts". Later, I worked as an SEO expert myself with great success. There is no "secrets" in SEO, there is a whole industry where SEO-people are fooling other people, and take good advantages of people who wants to start a webshop or a website, not are able to distinguish between lie and truth. I have never seen a SEO-"expert" with in depth understanding of the web or how search engines works. In my earlier work, now I am only programmer, I have seen salesmen taken ridicolous prices for nothing. SEO = scam.

Comment: Got to agree here re seo = scam.